# Recommended nomenclature: a better term than "parent"?

Tags: python, oop, terminology

I am writing a connection-state keeping program based loosely on the "State" example [here](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/10/08/design-patterns-python-style/).

In the example, the class Radio passes a pointer (better term?) to AmState when instancing AmState:

```
class AmState(State):
    def __init__(self, radio):
    self.radio = radio

...
class Radio(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.amstate = AmState(self)
```

The example stores this pointer (?) in the name 'radio', but what would be the correct Python/OO term for this value?  I keep wanting to say "parent", but 'AmState's *parent* is 'State', not 'radio'.

What is the terminology I should be using here to minimize confusion when documenting my code?

Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of options, but there's nothing wrong with "parent".  Note that this isn't a great pattern in general, since you're creating a circular reference for every one of these objects, which makes GC less efficient and will give you headaches if you have any `__del__` methods.

Comment: I disagree with @Glenn Maynard about it being OK to use "parent" because that term is often used to designate the base class (or classes) of a derived class -- which is not what the OP is doing. In fact, that's exactly what I thought the question was going to be about from its title.

Comment: @martineau: "Parent" is a generic term used in describing hierarchies; classes are just one case where it's used.  It's in no way specific to classes.

Comment: Maybe I just don't get it, but I think the State example you linked to is pretty strange. Python doesn't need state objects, we have generators to keep state.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: I agree, _technically_ "parent" is correct.  But I found myself thinking "parent class" every time I saw 'self.parent'.  If I'm getting confused while I'm developing the code, it's only gonna be worse when I (or someone else) comes back later and tries to understand it.  Hence the call for recommended alternatives.  Basically, the term "parent" is (too) overloaded.  :-)

Comment: If you find that confusing, you're going to have trouble dealing with any code dealing with trees or filesystems.

Comment: My old "file system" was made from trees.  I'll be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual term for this sort of composition is "owner". And the "better term" you're looking for is "reference".

Comment: +1: Totally agree with "reference" and the term "owner" make sense since from the code snippet it looks like a `Radio` *has a* `AmState`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose GOF Design Patterns is the nearest thing to canon, and it uses 'context'.

Comment: In the GOF *State* pattern a `Context` -- corresponding to `Radio` in the code snippet -- has a reference to a `State`, but they don't have reciprocal ones, unlike the code snippet. Based on other patterns in the book, a good name for that kind of reference might be "owner". Some others that come to mind, depending on the specific application, might be "controller" or "container".